# calling custom actions from File instead of Binary

Tags: file, binary, wix, windows-installer

I've found lots of examples of calling custom actions in WiX using Binary element, but none examples where a File element was used. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Just a side note: you limit yourself if you choose this approach. Obviously, the CA in the DLL you install can only run deferred and after InstallFiles action.

Comment: Good point, but I don't need them running non-deffered any way.

Comment: Similarly it can only be scheduled before RemoveFiles's deferred execution during an uninstallation.

Comment: You mean you want to call some function related to Files? like File.Exists() and all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not strictly true about needing to run the action deferred! You can use the InstallExecute action to run all the spooled actions up to that point, including, for example file installation. After that you could schedule an immediate action which depends on the newly-installed file, which at this point will be present.

That said, if the file is going to make any changes to the machine state, then the CA really needs to be deferred in system context, so InstallExecute doesn't really buy you anything.